# How to access a specific subview(UIWebView) of a UIScrollView and pass a line of Java to it

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, tags, uiscrollview, addsubview

I'm creating a `UIScrollView` and add four `UIWebViews` as subviews.

I would like to do two things:

1. Tag each `WebView`while creating it, to address it inside the `UIScrollView` later.
2. At a specific moment (`scrollViewWillBeginDragging`) send JavaScript to the `UIWebView` that is currently presented by the `UIScrollview`.

I don't know how to tag a subview nor how to address it. So my two questions are:

**Q1. How to properly tag a subview (while adding it to a UISCrollView)?**

**Q2. How to address a command to a subview inside the UIScrollView? ((best case: the on that is currently shown))**

*Thanks for your help!*

Maybe the Questions clarify by looking at the actual code:

Here is the code that I use to create the `UIWebviews` and add them to the `UIScrollview` (scrollView1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

scrollView1.delegate = self;
scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.delaysContentTouches = NO;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
UIWebView *WebView1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page_%d", i] ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[WebView1 loadRequest:request];


//HERE I'M TRYING TO TAG THE VIEW

WebView1.tag = i;

[scrollView1 addSubview:awesomeView];
[WebView1 release];

}
scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Here is the code that I would like to use to Address the `UIWebviews` inside the `UIScrollview` (scrollView1):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1{

NSString *JavaScriptCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player.pause();"];

<strong>//HERE I'M TRYING TO ACCESS THE TAGGED VIEW</strong>

[scrollView1.????? stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JavaScriptCommand];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
int i = // the tag of the webview you want to address   
[[scrollView1 viewWithTag:i] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JavaScriptCommand];
```

You could store the tag of the UIWebView that is currently presented in a member of your view controller class.

Comment: if i have scrollView1's tag=0, and then if i will access [scrollView1 viewWithTag:0] then it will print my scrollView... can you tell me why its happening?

Comment: That's because you gave the scrollView the tag 0. You must give the tag to the scrollviews' subview that you want to access. Also I would not use tag=0, because I think that might be the default value for all views. (not sure on that)

Comment: i am not giving tag to 0, it by default.. so whats the solution for this, start subView tag from 1 ?

Comment: Yes it's better to start with 1.